# Cursor inside for all in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing a package as follows :-

```
create or replace package body pack_name
    is 

    cursor is cur_get_data(p_run_id)
    is 
    select p_run_id run_id,
    person_id ,
    emp_name 
    from abc;


     TYPE demo_table_type IS TABLE OF get_demo_data%ROWTYPE;

       demo_table                         demo_table_type;

    procedure demo_data(p_data_array      IN     demo_table_type)
    is 

    cursor is cur_get_person(p_person_id number)
    is 
    select tot_comp_annual 
    from xyz;

    begin

     FORALL j IN 1 .. p_data_array.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        insert    
      INTO table_bad  (run_id,  person_id,emp_name)
     VALUES (p_data_array (j).run_id,
                           p_data_array (j).person_id,
                           p_data_array (j).emp_name);


    end;
```

Now the problem is  that i want to open cur_get_person and pass the person_id i am getting from p_data_array (j).person_id and insert that value in  table_bad's column annual_comp. How can i do that ?

Comment: with forall, it's not possible. Forall only admits one dml operation as far i know

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to not use a cursor. Instead, build the select from `xyz` into the `insert` statement. In general, you should avoid opening cursors inside of cursor loops; that's what joins are for.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_name IS
   CURSOR cur_get_data (p_run_id NUMBER) IS
      SELECT p_run_id run_id, person_id, emp_name FROM abc;


   TYPE demo_table_type IS TABLE OF get_demo_data%ROWTYPE;

   demo_table demo_table_type;

   PROCEDURE demo_data (p_data_array IN demo_table_type) IS
   BEGIN
      FORALL j IN 1 .. p_data_array.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
         INSERT INTO table_bad (run_id,
                                person_id,
                                emp_name,
                                tot_comp_annual)
            SELECT p_data_array (j).run_id,
                   p_data_array (j).person_id,
                   p_data_array (j).emp_name,
                   tot_comp_annual
            FROM   xyz
            WHERE  xyz.person_id = p_data_array (j).person_id;
   END;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to the cursor directly, or even indirectly via another collection (which generates an internal error, unless I'm doing something wrong). Allan's shown how to use combine the cursor query with the collection instead, but as what you seem to be doing doesn't seem to really need PL/SQL at all, I'm assuming you're just experimenting and are trying to combine things in convoluted ways on purpose. So here's a way to continue that theme, and use your cursor:

```
  procedure demo_data(p_data_array IN demo_table_type) is 

    cursor get_person_info is
      select person_id, tot_comp_annual
      from xyz;

    type comp_table_type is table of xyz.tot_comp_annual%type
      index by pls_integer;
    comp_table comp_table_type;

    type bad_table_type is table of table_bad%rowtype;
    bad_table bad_table_type := bad_table_type();
  begin

    -- intentioanlly convoluted, since the whole idea is; get all the
    -- info into another PL/SQL table
    for r in get_person_info loop
      comp_table(r.person_id) := r.tot_comp_annual;
    end loop;

    -- merge the two existing tables into a third with all the columns
    bad_table.extend(p_data_array.count);
    for j in 1 .. p_data_array.count loop
      bad_table(j).run_id := p_data_array(j).run_id;
      bad_table(j).person_id := p_data_array(j).person_id;
      bad_table(j).emp_name := p_data_array(j).emp_name;
      if comp_table.exists(p_data_array(j).person_id) then
        bad_table(j).tot_comp_annual :=
          comp_table(p_data_array(j).person_id);
      end if;
    end loop;

    forall j in 1 .. bad_table.count save exceptions
      insert into table_bad values bad_table(j);

  end demo_data;
```

This create a local PL/SQL table that all the `get_person_info` rows are bulk-fetched into. You can't use that directly in the `forall` either. But you can have a third PL/SQL table which is based on your target table, and populate that from both `p_data_array` and the collection holding your cursor data. This also simplifies the `forall` as you can insert the whole row in one go.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8339b/1).